# How to create a Child & Siblings menu for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, navigation

I am looking to create a menu that displays the child pages when on a parent page, but to then show the siblings when on any of the sibling's pages?

-Car
--VW
--Ford
--BMW
-Bike
-Motobike

So when on the Car page the output would be the following links:
**Car**, VW, Ford, BMW
and when on the Ford page the output would be the following links:
Car, VW, **Ford**, BMW

I have found some similar examples with the best one being https://learnwebcode.com/wordpress-child-page-menu-parent-and-subpages/ but this does not show an active menu item and also does not work for a custom post type.

```php
        <?php

        if ( has_children() OR $post->post_parent > 0 ) { ?>

            <nav class="site-nav children-links clearfix">

                <span class="parent-link"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(get_top_ancestor_id()); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(get_top_ancestor_id()); ?></a></span>

                <ul>
                    <?php

                    $args = array(
                        'child_of' => get_top_ancestor_id(),
                        'title_li' => ''
                    );

                    ?>

                    <?php wp_list_pages($args); ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        <?php } ?>
```

I am surprised there is not already an existing solution for this.

How do I create a menu from a custom post type that indicates the current page and shows the children if it a parent page and if it is a child page, it show the children from the same parent and the parent?

Comment: This plugin does that, in a widget: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-sidebar-menu/ You might want to check out its code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have cracked it. The below code seems to work well. To be able to use a custom post type I added an argument into the $args array`'post_type' => 'product',`

Is the below OK?

```php
      <div id="sub-pages">
        <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'product',
          'child_of' => get_top_ancestor_id(),
          'title_li' => ''
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
        <ul>
          <?php wp_list_pages($args); ?>
        </ul>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </div>
```

```php
// Get top ancestor
function get_top_ancestor_id() {

    global $post;

    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $ancestors = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
        return $ancestors[0];
    }

    return $post->ID;

}
```